# Select from multiple tables gives me an error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I have a query

```
const a = await prisma.$queryRaw`
SELECT r.name as name, r.profileId as profile, o.lastName as lastName
FROM UserSetting r , User o
WHERE r.userId=o.id
`
```

When I run that I get `relation "userSetting" does not exist` even though it does in prisma's model...
Even though i have the following relationship

`UserSetting`

```
user   Owner @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
userId Int
```

`User`

```
UserSetting UserSetting[]
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you created your tables and columns with double-quoted identifiers preserving upper-case letters. Now you have to double-quote those for the rest of their lives:

```sql
SELECT r.name, r."profileId" as profile, o."lastName"
FROM   "UserSetting" r, "User" o
WHERE  r."userId" = o.id
```

See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Oh, and a table named "User" is an accident waiting to happen, as `user` is also a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: Can you please help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72996231/get-maximum-number-of-job-slaves-per-instance-that-can-be-created-for-the-execut